# How to make a Multi-line (2 lines) label truncate the last line (OS X)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, truncate, nstextfield

I'm trying to make a multi-line label with 2 lines truncate the last line only. But it seems that, if I choose the `Layout` of that label as `Truncates`, my multi-line label becomes one-line.
Here's what I want (I manually typed "..." for demonstration purposes):
[image]
Here's what I have when I set my label as `Truncates` in IB (as you can see it still has 2 lines but acts as if it was only 1):
[image]


Is this supposed to happen? If not, how can I achieve the truncate style of the first image?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks as though you must have `Uses Single Line Mode` checked, which should be unchecked. Also, under `Layout` is the `Control` section, which can be set to specify which part of the label to truncate and whether to clip, wrap, and which portion to truncate (head, middle, tail).

> [ [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYJj1.jpg) ]  [image]