# Objective-C | Truncate only last line of multi line label on OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, truncate, nstextfield

I have a Multi Line Label and I want it to truncate only the last line tail. In the Attribute Inspector I set the options like the screenshot:

[image]

But it truncates always the first line.

This topic is a duplicate of this:
[How to make a Multi-line (2 lines) label truncate the last line (OS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20024349/how-to-make-a-multi-line-2-lines-label-truncate-the-last-line-os-x)
But I have had to open another one, because I don't have enough reputation to comment other people's topic.

Thanks for the replies!

Comment: "Truncates Tails" in Layout doesn't work?

Comment: In Layout there are only 3 options: Truncates, Clips, Wraps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change "Layout" to Wraps, which will change "Line Break" to Word Wrap, too. So long as "Truncates Last Visible Line" remains checked, you should get the result you want.

In other words, a Multi-Line Label just as it's dragged out from the Object library, tweaked by checking "Truncates Last Visible Line", does what you want.